# Leaflet sidebar within a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, leaflet, sidebar

I have a dataset with several points (latitude, longitude and some text for each), which I would like to show on a map, using Leaflet.
Instead of using Leaflet built-in popups, I am trying to use **leaflet-sidebar**, which allows to open a sidebar when a marker is clicked.

If you are interested, you can see an example (with one single marker) here:
https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/blob/master/examples/index.html

As you can see, I correctly open a sidebar for each marker, but the content of each `<div>` is shown **also below the map**.
This is due to the fact that I have the `<div>` within a PHP while loop, as follows:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)){
$i++;
$lat = $result['lat'];
$lon = $result['lon'];
$text = $result['some_text'];
?>

<div id="sidebar_<?=$i;?>" align="left">
<b>text</b>: <?=$some_text;?>
</div>

<script>
        var sidebar_<?=$i;?> = L.control.sidebar('sidebar_<?=$i;?>', {
        closeButton: true,
        position: 'left'
        });
        map.addControl(sidebar_<?=$i;?>);
        setTimeout(function () {
        sidebar_<?=$i;?>.hide();
        }, 500);
        var marker = L.marker([<?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $lon;?>]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
        sidebar_<?=$i;?>.toggle();
        });
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

If I place the `<div id="sidebar_<?=$i;?>">` outside the while loop, I can't collect each single marker lat/lon/text reference.

Do you have any tips on how to avoid this repetition below the map?

Comment: Are you including `L.Control.Sidebar.css`?

Comment: I am. As you can see, the plugin works (http://daado.fgfontana.eu/segnalazioni2.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround!

On the [plugin webpage](https://github.com/Turbo87/leaflet-sidebar) there is a note to add contents to `<div>` dynamically.
Basically, you need to leave the `<div>` empty in the html, and add content in the script part, using `setContent`:

```
<script>
        var sidebar_<?=$i;?> = L.control.sidebar('sidebar_<?=$i;?>', {
            closeButton: true,
            position: 'left'
        });

//HERE IT IS:

        sidebar_<?=$i;?>.setContent('<b>categoria</b>: <?=$categoria;?><br><br><b>problema</b>: <?=$descrizione;?><br><br><b>proposta</b>: <?=$soluzione;?><br><br><div class="smaller">data segnalazione: <?=$giorno."/".$mese."/".$anno;?></div>');

        map.addControl(sidebar_<?=$i;?>);
        setTimeout(function () {
            sidebar_<?=$i;?>.hide();
        }, 500);

        var marker = L.marker([<?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $lon;?>], {icon: iconarossa}).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
            sidebar_<?=$i;?>.toggle();
        });
</script>
```

Now it looks [as I wished](http://daado.fgfontana.eu/segnalazioni.php).

Comment: If you're adding content dynamically, do you still need multiple instances of the sidebar? Maybe you could add the relevant content just before you show the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display: none` to the style of the sidebar `<div>` -

```
<div id="sidebar_<?=$i;?>" align="left" style="display:none">
<b>text</b>: <?=$some_text;?>
</div>
```

You can probably do it a neater way with classes, but this should get you going.

Comment: I've already tried that. As a result, I get an empty sidebar. I think I need to  figure out how to put the <div> out of the while loop.

Comment: I added `display:none` to your `<div>`s in dev tools and it worked as you intended.